Apache Ranger Yarn Plugin Installation: Class Loading and Logging Configuration Problems

Class Loading Issue with Commons Logging: I have confirmed the presence of commons-logging*.jar in the directory /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/. Despite this, I am receiving errors indicating that the org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory class cannot be found.
SLF4J Binding Issues: Despite the presence of SLF4J bindings and the correct version of log4j-slf4j-impl jars within the same library directory, I continue to encounter the error: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Script Execution Context: All necessary jars (commons-logging, SLF4J bindings, Log4J implementation) are present and their paths are confirmed. However, the errors suggest that these are not being correctly recognized during the execution of the ./enable-yarn-plugin.sh script.

I am trying to install the Apache Ranger Yarn Plugin on YARN Resource Manager hosts and have encountered multiple issues related to class loading and logging configurations, which persist despite thorough troubleshooting. This is despite having successfully installed the Ranger HDFS Plugin without similar issues.
Environment:

Operating System: RHEL7
Apache Ranger Version: 2.4.0
Apache Hadoop Version: Bigtop 3.2.0 (hdfs:3.3.4-1; yarn:3.3.4-1)
Java Version: 8

install.properties
POLICY_MGR_URL=http://ranger_admin:6080
REPOSITORY_NAME=yarndev
COMPONENT_INSTALL_DIR_NAME=/usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn
XAAUDIT.SOLR.ENABLE=true
XAAUDIT.SOLR.URL=http://solr:8983/solr/ranger_audits
XAAUDIT.SOLR.USER=NONE
XAAUDIT.SOLR.PASSWORD=NONE
XAAUDIT.SOLR.ZOOKEEPER=NONE
XAAUDIT.SOLR.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=/var/log/hadoop/yarn/audit/solr/spool
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.ENABLE=false
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.URL=NONE
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.USER=NONE
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.PASSWORD=NONE
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.INDEX=NONE
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.PORT=NONE
XAAUDIT.ELASTICSEARCH.PROTOCOL=NONE
XAAUDIT.HDFS.ENABLE=false
XAAUDIT.HDFS.HDFS_DIR=hdfs://__REPLACE__NAME_NODE_HOST:8020/ranger/audit
XAAUDIT.HDFS.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=/var/log/hadoop/yarn/audit/hdfs/spool
XAAUDIT.HDFS.AZURE_ACCOUNTNAME=__REPLACE_AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
XAAUDIT.HDFS.AZURE_ACCOUNTKEY=__REPLACE_AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY
XAAUDIT.HDFS.AZURE_SHELL_KEY_PROVIDER=__REPLACE_AZURE_SHELL_KEY_PROVIDER
XAAUDIT.HDFS.AZURE_ACCOUNTKEY_PROVIDER=__REPLACE_AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PROVIDER
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.ENABLE=false
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.IS_ASYNC=false
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.ASYNC.MAX.QUEUE.SIZE=10240
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.ASYNC.MAX.FLUSH.INTERVAL.MS=30000
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.DESTINATION.LOG4J=true
XAAUDIT.LOG4J.DESTINATION.LOG4J.LOGGER=xaaudit
XAAUDIT.AMAZON_CLOUDWATCH.ENABLE=false
XAAUDIT.AMAZON_CLOUDWATCH.LOG_GROUP=NONE
XAAUDIT.AMAZON_CLOUDWATCH.LOG_STREAM_PREFIX=NONE
XAAUDIT.AMAZON_CLOUDWATCH.FILE_SPOOL_DIR=NONE
XAAUDIT.AMAZON_CLOUDWATCH.REGION=NONE
XAAUDIT.HDFS.IS_ENABLED=false
XAAUDIT.HDFS.DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=hdfs://__REPLACE__NAME_NODE_HOST:8020/ranger/audit/%app-type%/%time:yyyyMMdd%
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_BUFFER_DIRECTORY=__REPLACE__LOG_DIR/yarn/audit
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY=__REPLACE__LOG_DIR/yarn/audit/archive
XAAUDIT.HDFS.DESTINTATION_FILE=%hostname%-audit.log
XAAUDIT.HDFS.DESTINTATION_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS=900
XAAUDIT.HDFS.DESTINTATION_ROLLOVER_INTERVAL_SECONDS=86400
XAAUDIT.HDFS.DESTINTATION_OPEN_RETRY_INTERVAL_SECONDS=60
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_BUFFER_FILE=%time:yyyyMMdd-HHmm.ss%.log
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS=60
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_BUFFER_ROLLOVER_INTERVAL_SECONDS=600
XAAUDIT.HDFS.LOCAL_ARCHIVE_MAX_FILE_COUNT=10
XAAUDIT.SOLR.IS_ENABLED=true
XAAUDIT.SOLR.MAX_QUEUE_SIZE=1
XAAUDIT.SOLR.MAX_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS=1000
XAAUDIT.SOLR.SOLR_URL=http://solr:8983/solr/ranger_audits
SSL_KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH=/etc/hadoop/conf/ranger-plugin-keystore.jks
SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=myKeyFilePassword
SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILE_PATH=/etc/hadoop/conf/ranger-plugin-truststore.jks
SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=changeit
CUSTOM_USER=yarn
CUSTOM_GROUP=hadoop

# ./enable-yarn-plugin.sh
Current ClassPath: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*
Custom user and group is available, using custom user and group.
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : yarn: lib folder=/usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib conf folder=/usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-policymgr-ssl.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-policymgr-ssl.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-yarn-audit.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-yarn-audit.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-yarn-security.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-yarn-security.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving current config file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-policymgr-ssl.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-policymgr-ssl.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving current config file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-yarn-audit.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-yarn-audit.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving current config file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/ranger-yarn-security.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.ranger-yarn-security.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving current config file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/etc/hadoop/.yarn-site.xml.20240718-134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving lib file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-plugin-classloader-2.4.0.jar to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/.ranger-plugin-classloader-2.4.0.jar.20240718134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving lib file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-yarn-plugin-impl to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/.ranger-yarn-plugin-impl.20240718134106 ...
+ Thu Jul 18 13:41:06 +05 2024 : Saving lib file: /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-yarn-plugin-shim-2.4.0.jar to /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/.ranger-yarn-plugin-shim-2.4.0.jar.20240718134106 ...
Unable to store password in non-plain text format. Error: [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.<clinit>(FileSystem.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.initFileSystem(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.JavaKeyStoreProvider$Factory.createProvider(JavaKeyStoreProvider.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory.getProviders(CredentialProviderFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.ranger.credentialapi.CredentialReader.getDecryptedString(CredentialReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.ranger.credentialapi.buildks.createCredential(buildks.java:87)
        at org.apache.ranger.credentialapi.buildks.main(buildks.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 11 more]
Exiting plugin installation

# ls -lah /usr/bigtop/3.2.0/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/
total 5.1M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8.0K Jul 18 14:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   17 Jul 17 18:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  61K Jul 17 18:23 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-adapters.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-api.jar
-rw------- 1 root root  71K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 357K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-javadoc.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  83K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-tests.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124K Jun 30 18:08 commons-logging-1.3.3-test-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  61K Jul 18 11:33 commons-logging.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 468K Jun 30 18:08 findsecbugs-plugin-1.13.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 473K Jul 18 14:33 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 204K Jul 18 14:35 log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 348K Jul 18 12:05 log4j-1.2-api-2.23.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 295K Jul 18 14:33 log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 335K Jul 18 12:01 log4j-api-2.23.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.9M Jul 18 12:01 log4j-core-2.23.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27K Jul 18 14:02 log4j-slf4j2-impl-2.23.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K Jul 18 14:02 log4j-slf4j-impl-2.23.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23K Jul 18 14:02 log4j-to-slf4j-2.23.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   75 Jul 18 14:35 ranger-plugin-classloader-2.4.0.jar -> /usr/local/ranger-2.4.0-yarn-plugin/lib/ranger-plugin-classloader-2.4.0.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   63 Jul 18 14:35 ranger-yarn-plugin-impl -> /usr/local/ranger-2.4.0-yarn-plugin/lib/ranger-yarn-plugin-impl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   73 Jul 18 14:35 ranger-yarn-plugin-shim-2.4.0.jar -> /usr/local/ranger-2.4.0-yarn-plugin/lib/ranger-yarn-plugin-shim-2.4.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41K Jul 17 18:23 slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41K Jul 18 11:33 slf4j-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12K Jul 17 18:23 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12K Jul 18 11:33 slf4j-log4j.jar

# jar tf commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/commons/
org/apache/commons/logging/
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/
META-INF/NOTICE.txt
META-INF/LICENSE.txt
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/AvalonLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$1.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk14Logger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/ServletContextCleaner.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$WeakKey.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/NoOpLog.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogKitLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$3.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$1.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Referenced.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog$1.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Jdk13LumberjackLogger.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$2.class
org/apache/commons/logging/impl/WeakHashtable$Entry.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogSource.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$4.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$3.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$6.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$5.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$1.class
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$2.class
org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/commons-logging/
META-INF/maven/commons-logging/commons-logging/
META-INF/maven/commons-logging/commons-logging/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/commons-logging/commons-logging/pom.properties

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

File Integrity Checks: Verified the integrity of commons-logging and SLF4J jars using jar tf to list contents, confirming that the files are not corrupt.
Permissions and Security Settings: Ensured that file permissions are correctly set for all user access and that no security policies (like SELinux) are interfering with file access.
Verbose Class Loading Diagnostics: Enabled verbose class loading in Java to try to pinpoint which classes are being loaded and from where, which confirmed that certain classes are not being loaded as expected.

Impact:
This issue is blocking the successful installation and configuration of the Apache Ranger Yarn Plugin, affecting the deployment of security management in a Hadoop environment.
Requested Assistance:
I am seeking assistance to resolve these class loading and configuration issues to successfully install and configure the Apache Ranger Yarn Plugin. Any insights into potential misconfigurations or additional troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
